# Most appropriated simulator?

Tags: ros, simulation, uav

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What software package would you suggest to simulate a team of UAVs in USAR scenarios?
Required features:

1. 3D
2. realistic outdoor environments
3. multiagent
4. simulation of the appropriate sensors (IMU, GPS, cameras, ...)
5. ROS integration

We will use some AscTec firefly but any simulated quadrotor would be fine.

I tried USARSim which has all the required features but lacks the integration with ROS. There's an open source (wannabe) bridge project [USARSimRos](https://sourceforge.net/projects/usarsimros/) that should do the job but has some bugs (e.g. [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/usarsimros/discussion/general/thread/baca98c8/)). Nothing unresolvable but before reinventing the wheel I am scouting for alternative solutions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97551/most-appropriated-simulator?/) by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2013-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that [Gazebo](http://www.gazebosim.org/) should cover these features as well.

Have you looked at what others have done with the [hector_quadrotor](http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/tags:hector_quadrotor,gazebo/page:1/query:hector_quadrotor/) package?

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-11-04**:
Thank you tringhost, in fact I am about to try the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials), as soon as the gazebo installation is done... :-)
One concern: do you know of any ready-made outdoor scenarios available?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-11-05**:
I made the simple outdoor scenario that is used in the outdoor demo, but creating your own is pretty easy if you add the the required Gazebo models (or just drag and drop some of the existing ones into your simulated world).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

V-Rep should be interesting: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArAo334oSzo .
You can try it without spending much time, because using the build-in models is very intuitive.

You can also look at MORSE.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-11-04**:
Thank you Michael, V-REP is currently the best candidate. However the main drawback - AFAIK - is that it lacks realistic outdoor scenarios.

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-11-04**:
Also, I did not know [MORSE](http://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse/), I will take a look at it, thank you again.